# jQuery UI Datepicker - disable today's date if today is Monday?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

jQuery UI Datepicker:

Hi,

I'm trying to have the pop-up calendar allow only the Monday dates in the future to be selected.  I've tried this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dateWeekly').datepicker({
        showOn: 'both', // use to enable calendar button and focus 
        buttonImage: 'childtime/images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Show Calendar',
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: -0, maxDate: '+12M',
        // beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 1,""]}
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { return [date.getDay() == 1, "" && date.getTime() != today.getTime(), ""]; }
    });
});
```

This disables all past dates, and disables all future days except Mondays (so far so good), but it fails to disable today's date if today is Monday.  Any suggestions will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: by default it shows today's date. You dont need to configure it to show current date

Answer (score 0):

Set `minDate` to `+1d`.

As you are supposed to pick only *future* mondays, today shouldn't be able to be picked, no matter what day it is.

And you can simplify your beforeShowDay to:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [date.getDay() == 1, ""];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Code might be the solution for this question.

```
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { 
          returnFlag = true;    
              currentDate = new Date();
          if( date.getDay() == 1 && date.getDate() == currentDate.getDate()  
                                 && date.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()){
                returnFlag = false;
          }
          return [returnFlag,'',false];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that could help

```
$(function() {
  $('#dateWeekly').datepicker({
    showOn: 'both', // use to enable calendar button and focus 
    buttonImage: 'childtime/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: 'Show Calendar',
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: -0, maxDate: '+12M',
    beforeShowDay: function(date) { 
      // from here
      var selectable = true;
      var today = new Date()
      if( today.getDay() == 1 && date.getDate() == today.getDate() )selectable = false;
      return [selectable,'',false];
      // til here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for neg, but this is just wrong. You have to compare `date.getDay() == 1` and not `today`, and [`.getDate()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getdate.asp) returns the day of the month, not the "date value", so this comparison won't work either. And you have to do an `||` instead of an `&&`

Comment: date.getDay() outputs day of the week, and 1 is monday, so maybe you had not read completely the code i wrote.

Comment: Ok, after looking at it again I see the logic, but it's still wrong. Your logic is that if today is a monday and the date we are checking is today, disable it. But that's not what your code does. `today.getDay() == 1` is correct, but the other condition is wrong. You're just comparing the day of the month, but not what month or year it is. So if today is the 12th of July 2010 (a monday), it will disable the 12th of August, 12th of Sept etc because these are on the same_day_ as today. In addition, you are not enabling only mondays to be picked (aka `date.getDay() == 1`)