# jQuery UI DatePicker Allow Past Dates, Show Today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery UI DatePicker for an event app. Very often, I will have say an event that runs every Tuesday all year.

Now, the datepicker allows people to register for attendance reasons, so I would like to allow people to register for past dates, however, when the page loads, I want it to show the current month. Right now, it shows the start date of the event:

```
<%
event == event

    date_to_use_for_max_dates = event.end_date.nil? ? event.start_date : 
      event.end_date

    date_to_use_for_max_dates = date_to_use_for_max_dates > Date.today ? 
      date_to_use_for_max_dates : Date.today

    event_dates = event.get_occuring_dates(event.start_date, 
      date_to_use_for_max_dates.advance(:years => EventRsvp::REGISTRATION_MAX_CHECK_YEARS))

    min_date = [event_dates.first.strftime("%m"), event_dates.first.strftime("%d"), 
     event_dates.first.strftime("%Y")]

    max_date = [event_dates.last.strftime("%m"), event_dates.last.strftime("%d"), 
     event_dates.last.strftime("%Y")]

    event_dates_for_the_month = event_dates.collect{|d| d if d.month == 

    event_dates.first.month }.compact.collect{|d| [d.strftime("%m"), d.strftime("%d"), 
      d.strftime("%Y")] }

    registered_dates = event.get_registered_dates(current_user).collect{|d| 
      [d.strftime("%m"), d.strftime("%d"), d.strftime("%Y")] }
      url_for_registration_details ||= registration_details_for_day_event_path(event)
%>
```

and then the actual calendar:

```
<div id="event-calendar" data-event-name="<%= event.name %>" data-dates-url="
  <%= occuring_dates_event_path(event) %>" data-registrations-url="<%= 
  url_for_registration_details %>" data-min-date="<%= min_date %>" 
  data-max-date="<%= max_date %>" data-event-dates="<%= event_dates_for_the_month
  %>" data-registered-dates="<%= registered_dates %>"></div>
```

I tried changing the event dates to start today, but then someone can't register for events in the past.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check these it will give you a right direction http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Datepicker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247656/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-todays-date-if-today-is-monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the default date with the [`defaultDate` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate), though it's a bit hard to tell if this would actually work in your setup.  Is there any javascript code you call to trigger the datepicker?

Comment: It turns out one was selected and was hidden. Then I had to re-jiggle it to get it to refresh to show all the dates, but all is fixed. Thanks Samarth and RecursivelyIronic